# Consume with Spark Streaming from a specific Kafka Topic with a delay

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm consuming messages with Spark Streaming from topics in kafka and it works just fine.

However I would like to consume from a specific topic with a given delay (Like if the records are coming one by one with a delay).

For example : Consume records from Test_1 topic every 2 min and from Test_2 topic every 5 sec.

Is it possible to achieve that ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: No, that's not possible. The batch time for all topics is fixed with Spark Streaming.

Comment: Okey, Thank you for your fast response

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  What's the usecase behind?

Comment: @maasg I'm actually generating a production line machines outputs, since I don't have real sensors producing data to kafka. I have those outputs in files and I would like to consume those data 'gradually' like if it was coming from the sensors. So my results (with spark streaming) can be realistic

Comment: Probably a better way to approach that scenario is to write a Kafka Producer that simulates the expected load. Here's some code to get you started: https://github.com/maasg/ControllableDataProducer

Comment: @maasg thank you for your help ! I will try to do that

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov could you add that as an answer to accept and close this question?